# Closing an app in the background

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios, background

Suppose I have an iOS app that is actually running in the background (for one of several legal reasons, such as background audio, requested time, etc.).  What things might cause the OS to close (kill) this app instead of just running or suspending it?  How can I avoid them?  How can I reliably trigger them (within this app) using public APIs?

Comment: In other words, your question is: how do I designate my app as super-important so that the OS does not assert its power over it? In most cases, the answer is "you cannot". The OS designers justify this design by asking back: "What if all apps do the same?" Case in point: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/06/07/426294.aspx

Comment: If multiple backgrounded apps retain less dirty memory and etc.(the subject of the question), more of them can be left running in the background.  The number will still be finite, but larger, which might be better.

Comment: Unfortunately, assuming good faith and reasonable competence of 3rd party developers is not how a good end-user OS is made. What if a buggy or memory-hungry by design app tells the OS not to touch it?

Comment: Buggy or memory hungry implies that the app is asking NOT to be left running in the background.  Doesn't it?

Comment: Implies? How? The developer does not necessarily realize it's buggy and a memory hog.

Comment: How to develop an app that's not buggy and a memory hog is a general question that applies to ALL apps.  It's not particular to my question.

Answer (score 3):

Your app might be killed if it uses too much memory, if it does not call `endBackgroundTask:` when the expiration handler (specified when calling `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:`) is called, if the user explicitly kills it, if the app throws an exception, calls `exit`, triggers an EXC_BAD_ACCESS or other signal, and so on. There are probably other reasons, too.

To avoid these, don't use too much memory, call `endBackgroundTask:` when required, make an app that users won't want to kill, and don't throw exceptions, call `exit`, access invalid memory locations, and so on.

There isn't a way to reliably trigger "user explicitly kills the app". For the others, you could allocate tons of memory, refuse to call `endBackgroundTask:`, use `[NSException raise:... format:...]`, call `exit`, or create random garbage pointers and follow them. You probably shouldn't actually do any of these, though.

Comment: Calling exit() or dereferencing a bad pointer doesn't seem be a public API.  But trying to alloc tons of memory or not calling endBackgroundTask seems to be a "legal" use of public APIs.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're asking - it sounds like you want to be able to terminate *other* applications, which (thankfully) simply isn't possible on the iOS platform due to sandboxing, etc.

However, the most likely reason your own application will be killed whilst it's running in the background is if it's using a large amount of memory, etc. and doesn't respond to the `didReceiveMemoryWarning` calls by shedding resources that are no longer required.

In terms of automatically triggering these, the simplest way would be to use the "Simulate memory warning" option within the "Hardware" menu on the simulator.